# Pointer + LinkedList: Why am I getting this error?

Tags: c++, oop, pointers

I have a Queue class that holds a private LinkedList variable. The LinkedList holds DataItem pointers.

```
class Queue
{  
  private:

   LinkedList* someList;

...
```

The Queue then tries to add a DataItem using this Add method:

```
void Queue::addOne(DataItem* data)
{

  someList->add(data);

}
```

It is important to note that the LinkedList class works perfectly.

The program crashes spectacularly when it tries to add something to the Queue. What's going on?

Comment: Show the code for `add` ? How is `someList` initialized ?

Comment: ... Do you ever initialize `someList` to contain the head node?

Comment: the LinkedList works after declaration and adding anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is very vague and the code is not representative... maybe you forgot to allocate `someList`...?

Comment: This might be it. How do I allocate it? I'm assuming in the Queue's constructor, but how?

Comment: LinkedList someList was added to the constructor but I think this is just a declaration.

Comment: Well, we would need to see what the default constructor for `LinkedList` looked like. You might not even need to use a pointer, which would save you the trouble of a `new` allocation and having to properly free the memory when the `Queue` is destructed.

Comment: `free()` is for C. `new` allocations should be `delete`d

Comment: The default constructor is basic, setting the Head and 2 other nodes to NULL.

Comment: If the constructor is trivial then no need to store it as a pointer.

Comment: I'm storing objects in the LinkedList.

Comment: "> I'm storing objects in the LinkedList." 
so what?

Comment: I'm certain my understanding here is lacking, but if the LinkedList stores object references, I'm assuming it has to accept pointers....

Comment: If the problem is your lack of understanding, it might be a good idea to do as multiple people have requested and put up your add function so that it can be examined.

Comment: I got it to work by not making the LinkedList a pointer to a Linked List in the Queue class.